# hidden fields in migrating recaptcha to v2

Tags: c#, recaptcha

The original code

```
            @Html.Hidden("hf-register-publickey", SettingsHelper.CaptaPublicKey, new { id = "hf-register-publickey" })
            <div class="editor-field">
                <script src="@string.Format("{0}/recaptcha/api/challenge?k={1}", SettingsHelper.CaptaHost, SettingsHelper.CaptaPublicKey)" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <div id="captcha_contain"></div>
              <noscript>
                    <iframe src="@string.Format("{0}/recaptcha/api/noscript?k={1}", SettingsHelper.CaptaHost, SettingsHelper.CaptaPublicKey)"
                            height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    <br />
                    <textarea id="recaptcha_challenge_field" name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
             </textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"></input>
                </noscript>
            </div>
```

My question is on the first line. Do I still need the hidden fields with v2? I can't find any docs that address this.

Comment: If it works without them, then no. If it doesn't, then yes.

Comment: @stuartd There is that.